# "peer @angular/common@"9 - 13" from @fullcalendar/angular@5.11.0" Error while deploying in Netlify

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, netlify

```
Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.11.0
    npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
    npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
    npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
    npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
    npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
    npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: task-it-simple-web@0.0.0
    npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.1.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
    npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.1.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"9 - 13" from @fullcalendar/angular@5.11.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular
    npm ERR!   @fullcalendar/angular@"^5.11.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! See /opt/buildhome/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-07-25T18_42_47_447Z-debug-0.log
    Error during NPM install
    Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
```

I searched for this problem. But everywhere I get the solution to use `--force` on `npm install`. But what should I do to deploy on Netlify.

Note: I am not using any Custom CI/CD. Just added the branch in Netlify to build on push to branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v6/angular) for the Fullcalendar V6 Beta compatible with Angular V14

Answer (score 1):

`FullCalendar` v5 currently support Angular till version 13 ([reference](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular#supported-angular-versions))

So, if you really need `FullCalendar` you might need to downgrade version of Angular.

Comment: Is there any alternative to use in in Angular 14?

Comment: No idea, I never use this lib before.  You can track on this Github issue for future information. https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/issues/404